# Is it possible to transate the wParam parameter into the actual message string?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, qt4

I am trying to get the actual system messages that are represented by the intergers returned in the wParam property of the message. Is there anyway to do this or a function that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this is a question about WndProc? Which message are you talking about?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND p_hwn,UINT p_msg,WPARAM p_wparam,LPARAM p_lparam)
```

The WParam is generally used to send flags or info attached to a windows message,  it doesn't tell you what the message is.

The message id (p_msg) tells you what message it is e.g. 'WM_CHAR', 'WM_KEYDOWN' etc?  Is it these you are after?  If so you can download an enumeration here (C# but easy to convert):

```
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cswindowsmessages.aspx
```

Or of course just look in the C++ windows headers.

Comment: I need to translate the WM Flags to their equivalent string representation. Sorry I wasn't clear about that. I need to know what the interger translates to as a message. I looked at the windows.h header file and found nothing inside.

Comment: @dark - If I understand correct you'd be looking in 'winuser.h'